# Angular - Getting route parameter directly in template

Tags: angular, routes

Sometimes I have routes with several parameters like:

`/checklists/:type/:view/:filter`

I'd like to create links in the template this way:
`<a routerLink="['/checklists',':type',':view',':filter']">Link</a>`

Where the for example `:type` should be changed to the current value of the route's type parameter automatically, and add unique value for `:view` just for fun.

Currently, I have to do this for the same result:

```
  public path2url(path,params,custom_params={}){

    let path_pieces = path.split('/');
    let url_pieces = [];
    for( let pk in path_pieces){
      let piece = path_pieces[pk];
      if(piece.match(/^\:/)){
        let param_name = piece.replace(':','');
        piece = custom_params[param_name] || (params[param_name] || piece);

      }
      url_pieces.push(piece);
    }

    let url = url_pieces.join('/');

    //console.log('path2url',path,params,custom_params,url);
    return url;

  }
```

`<a routerLink="path2url(route_.path,route_.params,{'view':'map'})">Link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`queryParams`** as follows.

```
<a routerLink="['/checklists']" [queryParams]="{ type: 'typeVariable', view: 'viewVariable', filter: 'filterVariable'}">Link</a>
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but this seems to be setting not getting the parameter. I guess 'typeVariable' string is not a wildcard of the routeParameter

Comment: You should replace your actual variables with typeVariable, viewVariable and filterVariable

Comment: But that's the question, I don't know the value of typeVariable and I want to avoid to assign variables in the component.ts

Comment: If you use `queryParams` every param should have value. I am not clear what you want to do. can you explain in detailed what you need ?

Comment: Updated the question, it's pretty straightforward now